# Как проверить корректность результатов электронного голосования выборов 2021?

Tags: криптография, шифрование, блокчейн

Итак, голосование в ГД 2021 было проведено на блокчейне, при помощи ПО с открытым исходным кодом.

Что я могу сделать, чтобы проверить, что результат не был сфальсифицирован?

На сайте mos.ru выложены публичный и приватный ключи голосования. Как следует их использовать? Последняя транзакция в блокчейне содержит расшифрованные результаты голосования. Как я могу проверить, что между расшифровкой и публикацией не было подмены результата? Я должен сам зашифровать последнюю транзакцию и сравнить с предыдущей? При помощи какого алгоритма и с какими параметрами?

Comment: покажите ключи и ссылку на блокчейн транзакции и неплохо бы ссылку на ПО, которое использовалось для всего этого

Comment: Все эти вопросы - к разработчикам того самого ПО. Я в разработке 35 лет и, поверьте, лучшее, что вы можете сделать - это забить на всё это.